# Is it moderation tools or moderator tools?

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, wording

Once a user reaches 10K reputation they gain access to the [moderation tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools), or is it moderator tools?

[image]

Can we pick one and use consistent wording?

Comment: As far as I have seen, it seems to be called "moderator tools" everywhere except in the text of that link you show. The [privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) also calls it moderator tools. So I guess that is the intended name...

Comment: Probably an awkward grammatical tie-in to the first words encountered at the link: "Moderation privilege awarded at 10,000 reputation (newline) 
What is moderation?". --- IE: What you are using the moderator tools for is moderation; but you are not a(n elected) moderator. --- The awkwardness of the *free model*, like when you work at XYZ Company and they call you an "Associate"; but your not part owner, you simply *donate* over 50% of your wages to work there.

Comment: Why is it called tools... if it contains no tools?